# adding appengine eclipse plugin to ADT eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-adt, gae-eclipse-plugin

I download the eclipse [bundle for android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download). Now I want to add the Appengine plugin to eclipse. Should I download a separate instance of eclipse for Appengine or may I add GAE(Google App Engine) to the ADT eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer you based on intuition here, but I think you should be able to add GAE plugin to Eclipse you have (With ADT). Just install the plugin from local directory and try doing some basic GAE operations like deploying an app and it should be clear if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can install the GAE plugin to ADT Eclipse following the instructions below:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download